# Is a nested "if" loop necessary when using .instance_of()?

Tags: ruby

From: [CodeQuizzes #6, problem #2](http://www.codequizzes.com/topics/24/quizzes/80):

```
result = []
weird_array = ["blah", :meow, 42, 90, :building]
```

Iterate over every element of `weird_array` and add the element to the result array if the element is a :Symbol (i.e. an instance of the Symbol class).

The proposed solution:

```
weird_array.each do |element|
  if element.instance_of?(Symbol)
    result.push(element)
  end
end
```

But, since `#instance_of?` returns a Boolean, wouldn't this work as well?:

```
weird_array.each do |x|
  result << x.instance_of?(Symbol)
end
```

(I ran the two in **IRB** and got back similar answers, but just want to double-check with you experts.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No*, this would add either `true` or `false` to the `result` array, not the object `x` itself. This is not what the exercise asks.

This would work though:

```
weird_array.each do |x|
  result << x if x.instance_of?(Symbol)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could make the `if` implicit by using `select`:

```
result = weird_array.select { |x| x.instance_of? Symbol }
```